# How to update argument passed to context manager during code execution?

Tags: python, arguments, contextmanager

`node` is passed to the context manager, which I want to lock at the beginning, then do some work, at last unlock the node. But if `node` is changed during the execution inside the with clause, how do I pass the updated `node` to `unlockFunc` ?

This code runs in python 2.7

```
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def call(begin, end, *args, **kwargs):
    begin(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        end(*args, **kwargs)


def lockFunc(*args):
    print 'in lockFunc'
    print 'lock %s' %args[0]


def unlockFunc(*args):
    print 'in unlockFunc'
    print 'unlock %s' %args[0]


node = 'old-node'
with call(lockFunc, unlockFunc, node):

    print 'in with'
    # update node value here
    node = 'new-node'
```

But the output is

```
in lockFunc
lock old-node
in with
in unlockFunc
unlock old-node
```

How can I let `unlockFunc` know that `node` has been changed.

edit: I have tried making `node` a list, but that does not work.

edit2:
I tried using a list, it works this way.

```
node = ['old-node']
with call(lockFunc, unlockFunc, node):

    print 'in with'
    node[0] = 'new-node'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `node = 'new-node'` doesn't change the object that the contextmanager has a reference to; it changes what the identifier `node` refers to.

You need instead to tell the object to change, and you can only do this with a mutable object; strings are not mutable.  A list would work, but I think a class is probably a bit clearer:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value

    def update(self, newvalue):
        self.value = newvalue

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

@contextmanager
def call(begin, end, *args, **kwargs):
    begin(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        end(*args, **kwargs)


def lockFunc(*args):
    print 'in lockFunc'
    print 'lock %s' %args[0]


def unlockFunc(*args):
    print 'in unlockFunc'
    print 'unlock %s' %args[0]


node = Node('old-node')
with call(lockFunc, unlockFunc, node):

    print 'in with'
    # update node value here
    node.update('new-node')
```

which produces

```
in lockFunc
lock old-node
in with
in unlockFunc
unlock new-node
```

(Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7.6)

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution.

```
class call(object):

    def __init__(self,begin, end, *args, **kwargs):
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __enter__(self):
        self.begin(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return self

    def __exit__(self,exc_type,exc_val,trcback):
        self.end(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def lockFunc(*args):
    print 'in lockFunc', args
    print 'lock %s' %args


def unlockFunc(*args):
    print 'in unlockFunc'
    print 'unlock %s' %args

node = 'old-node'

with call(lockFunc, unlockFunc, node) as c:
    print 'in with'
    # update node value here
    c.args = ('new-node',)
```